# How to run my Xcode application by using iPhone?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an `iPod touch 6th generation`. I need to run my application using actual device. I dont have a 
`purchased apple ID`. I need to test my `application` without using purchased apple ID. Please give me good guidelines step by step.

Comment: Are you using Xcode 7 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Till Xcode 7 in order to load an app to iOS device, you need to code sign the app. But from Xcode 7, Apple have opened up this procedure.

Again, this doesn't work if you are trying to make an IPA file and then load, you need to select the device from Xcode and hit Run button like below. [image]

Comment: In Xcode 6.4 not working without developer(purchased) account.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Go to Build setting ->code signing Identity section set provisioning profile to Automatic and set certificate to IOS Developer it works for me Try it.

Comment: I have already created appleID (non paided). But the problem is every time I am trying to run my apps via xcode Its showing below alert error."No valid signing identities (i.e.certificate and private key pair)matching the team ID "(null)" were found.

Comment: just set team to None in general  settings.

Comment: Yes. I did but again i am facing same prblem

Comment: are you set above setup in both target and project's build setting?

Comment: Yes. I did.Please help me!

Comment: hey  thanks for accepting my ans plz upvote for my ans.

Comment: Urs not working for me first. I am usign Xcode 6.4 and iOS 8.4...tel me how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow as below in your **Build Settings** -> **Code Signing**

[image]